# Cannot update recycler view from GreenRobotEventBus

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, greenrobot-eventbus

From past two days, I am trying to set recycler view values received from Eventbus but getting error No adapter attached; skipping layout.
I have tried and tested every code that is available on internet like 
1. https://github.com/gunhansancar/eventbus-example appended data in adapter
2. [Trying to impact RecyclerView items via EventBus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51378699/trying-to-impact-recyclerview-items-via-eventbus) - creating method in adapter class but still nothing is happening

I am getting response in event but cannot use that response in recycler view

code

```
  @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    fun pickDropChooseEvent (data : PickAddressDone){
        try {
//vehicle list result is a model
            vehicleListResult = data.vehicleListResult

            vehicleAdapter.updateData(vehicleListResult.vehicleCategory!!);
            vehicleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        catch (exception : Exception )
        {
            Log.d("vehicle info" ,"catch pick drop "+exception.toString())
        }
    }
```

then in ViewCreated I have declared a method "initMembers" to initialise views of the fragment

```
 private fun initMembers() {
        try{
            vehicleList = ArrayList()
            vehicleList.addAll(vehicleListResponse.vehicleListResult!!.vehicleCategory!!)
            tvDistance.text = vehicleListResult.ride!!.distanceText
            rvVehicleList.setHasFixedSize(true)
            rvVehicleList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
            rvVehicleList.setAdapter(vehicleAdapter)
           vehicleAdapter = VehicleCategoryAdapter(context!!, vehicleList)


          // i have even tried notify change

        }catch (exception: Exception)
        {
            Log.d("vehicle info", " exception "+exception)
        }

    }
```

Update: It is resolved there was no issue in the code but issue was in the Xml ConstraintLayout..

```
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/grey_shadow_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/clRideInfo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" // this was causing the issue as height was not assigned to the constraint view. Recycler view is showing after removing it
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvVehicleList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:listitem="@layout/layout_vehiclelist_item" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thank you everyone

Comment: Are you getting data pickDropChooseEvent() in this method from event verify once.

Comment: yes I am getting data from event

Comment: first make sure dummy data is showing in list or not. Sometime issue is in xml part also. please verify that also.

Comment: its not showing. might be the error is in Adapter

Comment: @AmanpreetKaur can u please share the full code of related class.

Comment: yes please share full code

Comment: Place this `rvVehicleList.setAdapter(vehicleAdapter)` after `vehicleAdapter = VehicleCategoryAdapter(context!!, vehicleList)` in the `initMembers()` method

Answer (score 0):

You should call initMembers() method in onCreateView callback method not in ViewCreated

Comment: With this method, I can attach the adapter but changes are not reflected in the recycler view. It is still blank